# Report on Accounts with Count of A Custom_Object

Tags: reporting

I am trying to create a report that will do a bucket on the summary (by count) of a field in a custom object

I have a custom object: `License`, with a n-1 relation to Account.

- License is NOT a Master-Detail with Account

I added a [formula field](https://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=a1X30000000c0taEAA) `Number(1,0) = 1` on License, in order to be able to count how many licenses, each account has

[image]

What I need to accomplish now, is to be able to bucket the `Count` field. (pie chart for the display)

I have trouble fulfilling this last piece.

Comment: So you want to know how many accounts have 2 licenses, how many have 5 licenses, etc...?

Comment: yep, can't find the correct fine tuning for this

Comment: Is License a child in a Master-Detail to Account? If so, could you just do a rollup summary field on Account to derive that information

Answer (score 1):

click new report, choose accounts and contacts (ingnore subfeilds), then click run report. After you are viewing the full report, you can summarize information by your custom fields / objects

Answer (score 0):

**Config Only**

Without resorting to apex you're best option is going to be switching the relationship to a master-detail.  With the addition of a roll-up field you can use the count for filtering and bucketing (although this may require a formula field) in your reports.

**Apex**

Alternatively, if a master-detail isn't an option (usually the case if not all licenses are related to accounts), you'll want to build out a trigger to do the roll-up for you.

**AppExchange**

Finally, if you're okay with results not being real-time the free [Rollup Helper](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI) which lets you define custom rollups with points not clicks.

**Reporting**

Ideally you should be able to create a report formula field and then bucket it, but that doesn't appear to be possible at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Saariko If you want to get count of summary fields.My suggestion is to create a summary report and create a formula like count of All summary levels in selection.It is the best one because I had created recently a report like no of contacts on every account.

For Reference :
[image: Summary count]

I think it resolves your problem.